# How to read partition as a column from list of s3 paths in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How can I read a partition as column (withColumn) from list of s3 paths. I am iterating through dates and reading partition for each date in union each day and union them together to create final dataframe like below.

```
    rtn_df = None
    for each_day in (start_date + timedelta(d) for d in range(date_count)):
        path = s3_prefix + "/partition_country=" + country + "/partition_date={date}".format(
            date=each_day.strftime("%Y%m%d"))
           df = spark.read.load(path).withColumn(
            "partition_date", lit((each_day.strftime("%Y%m%d"))))
        if not rtn_df:
            rtn_df = df
        else:
            rtn_df = rtn_df.union(df)
```

However this approach is slow, instead of this I want to iterate through the dates and create list of paths and read them all together.
I am not able to figure out how to add `partition_date` as column name from list of paths with different `partition_date` values?

something like below:

```
    paths = []
    for each_day in (start_date + timedelta(d) for d in range(date_count)):
        path = s3_prefix + "/partition_country=" + country + "/partition_date={date}".format(
            date=each_day.strftime("%Y%m%d"))
        paths.append(path)
    rtn_df = spark.read.load(*paths).withColumn(
            "partition", "????????")
```

Comment: Are all the partition in a single path i.e single folder?
If yes you can leverage [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-csv.html)

Comment: I have partition for each date for multiple years and they are in the same base folder, something like `s3://base_bucket/table_name/partition_country=US/partition_date={}/files.parquet`

Comment: Have you tried `df = spark.read.format("parquet").load("s3://base_bucket/table_name/")`?
Additional reference: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-generic-options.html

Comment: Yes I did, if you use all the list of paths in `load()` then it wont read the partition columns. If I use the base path to read the data and filter on the partition columns then its very slow.

Answer (score 0):

There's a function called `input_file_name` that gets you the partition name:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as fn
df = df.withColumn("partition_name", fn.input_file_name())
```

Comment: this will read the entire file name as a column value and in the end I will have to use udf to parse the file name string and get the partition value.

Comment: You don't have to use a UDF, you can use one of the string manipulation functions, like `regexp_replace, regexp_extract, substring`, etc.